# Return the count value in java

Tags: java, date, jdbc, timestamp

Hi i have develop on example.
This is my code:

```
public class GetMonthFromDate {
  public int data() {
    int count=0;
    java.sql.Timestamp timeStamp = new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis());
    java.sql.Date date = new java.sql.Date(timeStamp.getTime()); 

    //count++;

    try {
      Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
      Connection con =
        DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/xcart-432pro",
                                    "root", "");

      PreparedStatement statement =
        con.prepareStatement("select * from xcart_order_status_history where date_time='date'");
      ResultSet result = statement.executeQuery();
      while (result.next()) {
        // Do something with the row returned.
        count++; //if the first col is a count.
      }
    } catch(Exception exc) {
      System.out.println(exc.getMessage());
    }

    return count;
  }
}
```

in above code is not worked for me.

Here i have use this code

```
java.sql.Timestamp timeStamp = new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis());
java.sql.Date date = new java.sql.Date(timeStamp.getTime());
```

means give the output is `2012-08-08` only. So only i have to call date in my code. but it is not work for me.displayed returns the count value is `0`. o is wrong. `2` only correct. because matched query have 2 values in my database.

```
select * from xcart_order_status_history where date_time='date'
```

Comment: inspite of your wrong jdbc code, i think you should use Calendar API  to instantiate your sql date, instead of invoking two constructors. here i wont tell you the code, you should explore that yourself

Answer (score 0):

You have not set the date value to the prepared statement.

Comment: how is set the date value to prepared statement

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
PreparedStatement statement = con.prepareStatement("select * from xcart_order_status_history where date_time=?");
statement.setDate(1, date);
```

you also should not do a select * if you only need the count. You should use select count(*)

Comment: the following message is displayed on my console Parameter index out of range (1 > number of parameters, which is 0).
0

Comment: Did you put the `?` in quotes?

Comment: ya the above code is worked and returns the count value is 2.but now my database date is saved in timestamp format.now how is i wrote the code for query

Comment: my database have one field.field name is date.that date field is save in timestamp(int) format

Answer (score 0):

Your usage of the PreparedStatement is totally wrong.

You don't pass variable names, you pass placeholders and then you to explicitely pass the values for them:

```
PreparedStatement statement =
    con.prepareStatement("select * from xcart_order_status_history where date_time=?");
statement.setDate(1, date);
ResultSet result = statement.executeQuery();
```

And you *never* put the `?` in quotes inside the statement. The adjustment to the datatypes will be handled by the JDBC driver.

You might want to re-read the JDBC tutorial. It seems that you have missed some basic concepts: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/index.html

Comment: the following message is displayed on my console Parameter index out of range (1 > number of parameters, which is 0). 0

Comment: ya the above code is worked and returns the count value is 2.but now my database date is save in timestamp format.now how is i wrote the code for query

Comment: @krishnaveni: I have no idea what you mean with "*database date is save in timestamp format*"

Comment: my database have one field.field name is date.that date field is save in timestamp(int) format.

Comment: @krishnaveni: So you have a column named `date`. What is your question?

Comment: yes.date column field is save in timestamp(int) format.so this timestamp format is converted to date and check the query for today date and returns the count value.how is to do.how ia wrote code for this

Comment: In prepared statement you also have setTimestamp() method use it.

Comment: how is add setTimestamp() method on prepared statement

Comment: @krishnaveni: you don't like reading JavaDocs and manuals do you?

Answer (score 0):

```
public class GetMonthFromDate {
    public int data() {
        ...
        java.sql.Timestamp timeStamp = new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis());
        ...
        PreparedStatement statement = con.prepareStatement("select * from xcart_order_status_history where date_time=?");
        statement.setTimestamp(1,timeStamp);
        ...

        return count;
    }
}
```

Comment: the following message is displayed on my console Parameter index out of range (1 > number of parameters, which is 0). 0

Comment: ya the above code is worked and returns the count value is 2.but now my database date is save in timestamp format.now how is i wrote the code for query

Comment: what do u mean? do u mean your column data type is timestamp and not date? is that so try `statement.setTimestamp(...)` instead of `setDate`. For more information how to use `setTimestamp` google it ;)

Comment: my database have one field.field name is date.that date field is save in timestamp(int) format

Comment: that is because the timestamp that you given in your code is the current system time. if you get zero, then you dont have data in that time. `date_time` does not have a record `System.currentTimeMillis()`. could you just show us the data in your table column `date_time`? Just add it to your question.